# MySQL 5.1 and partial query result

Tags: mysql

Goodmorning, I'm doing a query to fill a MFC Recordset in my program. Since the moment that I have a lot of rows in that table, I would load only a certain number of records at time.
Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require `LIMIT` clause in your `select` statement to get records in a range.

Notes from [*Select statement syntax*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html):

The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:

1. Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
   ? placeholder markers.
2. Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
```

In other words, `LIMIT row_count` is equivalent to `LIMIT 0, row_count`.

Answer (score 0):

try this ::

```
Select * from table limit 100
```

Comment: that solves the first page. Do you have an answer for him for subsequent pages? So he can load the certain number of records *at a time*?